# How to calculate the sum of multiple columns in hive

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have a question about hive.

In the table below

> I want to calculate all the sums from v1 to v100.

```
create table test
(v1 int,
v2 int,

...

v99 int,
v100 int);
```

I can calculate if I do as follows, but I would like to know how to describe it shorter.

```
select v1 + v2 + ... + v99 + v100 from test;
```

I investigated whether it can be written briefly using regular expression etc, but it was not found.

Comment: Your expression is the correct way to do this.